# Theorem 17.22 from Ian Stewart's Galois Theory

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions, separable-extension

> Apply the Frobenius map to minimal polynomials to see that $$ [K(\alpha^p+\beta^p):K(\alpha^p+\beta^p,\beta^p)]\leq [K(\alpha+\beta):K(\alpha+\beta,\beta)] $$ and $$ [K(\alpha^p+\beta^p):K] \leq [K(\alpha+\beta):K] $$

Let $\overline{K}$ be a fixed algebraic closure. Let $m_1$ be the minimal polynomial of $\beta^p$ over $K(\alpha^p+\beta^p)$ and let $m_2$ be the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $K(\alpha+\beta)$. If I can show that $m_1 \mid m_2$ in $\overline{K}[x]$ then this would be enough. But here I'm stuck, because I'm not sure how to use the Frobenius map, i.e. $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$, to show this. Similarly for the second inequality. Reference material is posted below.

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images, for the following reasons among others: (i) they cannot be searched, which will make it difficult for future users to find this post if it relates to their queries; (ii) screen readers cannot process them, making your post inaccessible to users who rely on them; and (iii) they cannot adapt to the user's display the way the site does, which means they may not display properly for some. The site has excellent typesetting capabilities for mathematical formulas, please avail yourself of them. If it is too much to type, then it is probably too much to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F:\bar{K}\to\bar{K},x\mapsto x^p$ denote the Frobenius map. Note that $F(K(\alpha+\beta))\subseteq K(\alpha^p+\beta^p)$. Consider the polynomial $F(m_2)$ ($F$ applied to the coefficients). Then $F(m_2)\in K(\alpha^p+\beta^p)[x]$ and $F(m_2)(\beta^p)=F(m_2)(F(\beta))=F(m_2(\beta))=0$. Thus $m_1\mid F(m_2)$ and therefore \begin{align*}
[K(\alpha^p+\beta^p,\beta^p):K(\alpha^p+\beta^p)]=\deg m_1&\leq\deg F(m_2)\\&=\deg m_2=[K(\alpha+\beta,\beta):K(\alpha+\beta)]
\end{align*}
The second inequality follows from $K(\alpha^p+\beta^p)\subseteq K(\alpha+\beta)$.